# Pre-process node type for each node and print within region.html.twig template

Tags: theming

I'm trying to figure out how I can check the node type/content type for each node using pre-process and print it on a region template `(region.html.twig)`

It seems to be returning `NULL`

```
function iom_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    $node = $variables["node"];
    $variables['content_type'] = load($node->bundle())->label();
}
```

`{{ content_type }}`

Comment: @NoSssweat Tried that a moment ago, but still returns `NULL`, `{{content_type}}` seems to be printing on `node.html.twig`, but it doesn't seem to work on `region.html.twig`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use preprocess region:

```
function iom_preprocess_region(&$variables) {
    $node = $variables["node"];
    $variables['content_type'] = $node->getType();
}
```

Clear/flush cache after adding it.